# Couldn't drag an element using Webdriver (Java Script)

Tags: javascript, web, selenium-webdriver

### Dragged an element using the following code -

"WebElement baseElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Element ID");

Actions clicker = new Actions(driver);

### clicker.moveToElement(baseElement).moveByOffset(20,0).click().perform();

The element is not being moved to offset position given, instead dragging till the possible end whatever the offset value is like (0,0,), (2,0) etc.

But the element dragged is moving to its orginal position after a second.

Manually this is not happening, and able to drag till the position I wish within the limit.

This is just drag element on a bar, not a drag a drop element.

Also tried different drag related methods but nothing is working and facing the same situation.

Please help me out if any one has faced the same situation.

Tried with Selenium 2.27 to 2.40 on FF 17ESR, 20 and 24ESR and the issue repeats.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below options.

**Option 1:**

```
WebElement eleFrom = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='draggable']"));
WebElement eleTo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='droppable']"));   
  Actions action = new Actions(driver); 
action.dragAndDrop(eleFrom, eleTo).perform();
```

**Option 2:**

```
Actions builder = new Actions(dr);       
Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(someElement) 
       .moveToElement(otherElement) 
       .release(otherElement) 
       .build(); 
dragAndDrop.perform();
```

**Option 3:**
We can use the below function in Actions class.

```
dragAndDropBy(WebElement source, int xOffset, int yOffset)
```

A convenience method that performs click-and-hold at the location of the source element, moves by a given offset, then releases the mouse.

Hope it helps, else feel free to revert.

Comment: There is no choice for using **Option 1** - as the drag and drop points are not fixed, its an index bar where the index values always keep on changing, and multiples of which number also cannot be determined.

**Option 2** - also I have tried with all the xpaths for that element but the same thing is happening, drags and replaces to the original position

**Option 3** - I will try it and let you know.

Thanks for the help.